# Prove that $|x^2(y − z) + y^2(z − x) + z^2(x − y)| < xyz.$

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

If $x, y, z$ are the sides of a triangle, then prove that
$|x^2(y − z) + y^2(z − x) + z^2(x − y)| < xyz.$

*This is a self-answered question.*

Answer (score 4):

The given inequality may be written in the form
$|(x − y)(y − z)(z − x)| < xyz.$
Since $x, y, z$ are the sides of a triangle, we know that $|x − y| < z, |y − z| < x$ and $|z − x| < y.$
Multiplying these, we obtain the required inequality.